# Create AddressBook group without creating individual contacts

Tags: macos, apple-mail, address-book, mailing-lists

Is there a way to create a mailing list for AddressBook.app and/or Mail.app without individually creating contacts for each person on the list?

Specifically, I have an e-mail addressed to each student in my class. (Each student's e-mail address is in the BCC field.)  I would like to create a mailing list with these addresses; but, because the class is relatively large, I don't want to individually create a contact for each student.  Is there a way to select the entire list of addresses and create a group in one step?

Comment: In what format do you have the emails now? in a spreadsheet or word document?

Comment: Neither.  Just an e-mail.  Specifically, I can log into the web interface of our student records system, dig through a bunch of menus, then click on a "mailto" link that generates a e-mail with all the addresses in the BCC field.  I can cut-and-paste the BCC field into TextEdit, but the result is quite "noisy":  I get names and e-mails mixed together.  I'm sure I could write a perl script to sort it all back out; but, I'm looking for a simpler solution.

Comment: Writing Perl script, would depend on the school's security system that is in place to. I know it is not the answer you want, but you may have to make an address book once at the start and then save yourself the work with future emails. At the moment it sounds like you are doing more work than that anyway.